# Go to previous controller in navigation stack (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertview

I am trying to popViewController to the previous View Controller in the navigation stack after an alertView.  As of now, my program will not run the popViewController method, since the alertView is in the way, and brings up the error:

```
    UINavigationController 0x17670900 while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

How do I go about running the popViewController method after the user clicks OK from the alertView?  Do I have to set a delegate which detects when the used clicks OK?

Here is my code:

```
    //alertView after Picture saved
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Record Saved to Database", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //go to previous controller using popViewController, doesnt work, brings up error message
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Comment: You are calling two transitions at the same time: present alert and pop previous view controller. 

Call present alert as you do now, but then in action handler, call popViewController. It will be called when the user taps OK button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pop the view controller when user presses the `Ok` button from AlertView.

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Success!", message: "Record Saved to Database", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (action) in
    // pop here
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
alertView.addAction(OKAction)
self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the "popViewControllerAction" inside an alert action like this.

func alertMethod() {

```
    var okAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Your title", comment: ""), message: "Your message", preferredStyle: 
    UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        // your action - navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        // your action
    }

    }

    saveAlertController.addAction(okAction)
    saveAlertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(okAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

That should work, in that case the method gets called after the user presses a button...